# create-react-app doesn't restart when changes happen in server code

Tags: create-react-app

using /src/setupProxy.js, I have import /server/index.js and start up a server api.

The trouble is that changes to files in /server/ directory do not restart the create-react-app so I don't see any of my changes until I kill it and restart it.

Is there a way to have create-react-app also watch the server directory for changes, or a way to use nodemon to run create-react-app?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you can do

`nodemon create-react-app start`

create-react-app does a better in place update in your browser when you make changes in the src directory, so you don't want nodemon triggering a restart in that case.

To avoid this, create a file called `nodemon.json`:

```
{
  "ignore": ["src/*", "build/*"]
}
```

And then nodemon will only restart for non-react stuff updating.

I added the build directory too as it shouldn't be part of the restart.